# Extract images files from .git repository

Tags: git

Is there a way to view and extract all the images that are in all the commits and all the branches in a git repository?
for example in a branch i add a image x.jpg and commit it, then i delete that image and add a new one y.jpg and commit it. in the repository still there is info about x.jpg in case i go back to the first commit. i wanna see all the images files in diferents commits and diferents branches. is there a way to do that? without going back to old commits to look files per files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git rev-list --all --objects
```

will get you a list of everything in history, you can do whatever you like with what it shows you, `git show` is the easy way to drop a blob's contents anywhere you like.  So for instance

```
git rev-list --all --objects \
| sed -nr 's/([^ ]*) (.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$/git show \1 >"\2-\1.\3"/p'
```

will print commands to drop all historical versions of those image-type files in your work tree.

Comment: thanks, that's what i looking for. It was useful to me. thanks again..

Comment: git show command example: `git show fc3aec83dafb3d68381b69d7fc3ba9004012f994 > test.jpg` This will write the file with object hash fc3... to test.jpg.

Answer (score -2):

git log will give you information about your commit history and you can go to the previous commit using git reset --head "commitId" I strongly advice using git reset with care

Comment: I'm trying to find some way that I don't have to review commit by commit, but in one go see all the files that the repository stores information about (inside the .git or .git / objects folder I guess)